# Cordova Contact API binding only name and phone Number

Tags: javascript, cordova, cordova-plugins, phonegap

I am using Corodva Contacts API in my project to get all local  phone contact details its working fine, I need to get both name and phone number and store in single variable array. Below is my code which i am trying but i am storing it names nad phoneNumber saparate,but i need to store both name and phoneNumber is single array.How i can achieve this kindly suggest.

```
   //Variable to store name and phonenumber list 
    var names = new Array();
    phoneNumberCollection = new Array();

 function GetContacts(){
    var options = new ContactFindOptions();
options.filter = "";
options.multiple = true;
options.desiredFields = [navigator.contacts.fieldType.id, navigator.contacts.fieldType.displayName, navigator.contacts.fieldType.name, navigator.contacts.fieldType.phoneNumbers];
options.hasPhoneNumber = true;
var fields = [navigator.contacts.fieldType.displayName, navigator.contacts.fieldType.name, navigator.contacts.fieldType.phoneNumbers];
navigator.contacts.find(fields,onSuccess, onError, options);
 }

function onSuccess(contacts) {
if (contacts.length != 0) {
    // get formatted names and sort

    for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; ++i) {
        if (contacts[i].name) {
            if (contacts[i].name.formatted) names.push(contacts[i].name.formatted);
        }}
    for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; ++i) {
        if (contacts[i].phoneNumbers) {
      if (contacts[i].phoneNumbers[0].value) phoneNumberCollection.push(contacts[i].phoneNumbers[0].value);
        }    }
       names.sort();
        }}
    } else alert("No record Found");
    }
```

Comment: i solved myself.